# Clocked procedure with array insertions VHDL

Tags: stored-procedures, vhdl, fifo, test-bench

I am trying to construct a procedure for my testbench that each clock cycle reads data from an external FIFO and insert the data into an internal array in the testbench.

My objective is for the procedure to read data from the FIFO until it is empty. The problem I am having is that it appears to only read one word before exiting the procedure.

```
procedure read_uplink_FIFO(
    signal clk            : in std_logic;
    )is
    variable rd_cnt       : integer := 0; 
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if fifo_empty_o = '0' then
            rd_ena_i    <= '1';
            uplink_fifo_reg(rd_cnt) <= rd_data_o;
            rd_cnt  := rd_cnt + 1;
        elsif fifo_empty_o = '1' then
            rd_ena_i    <= '0';
            rd_cnt      := 0;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

The procedure is called inside the testbench main process, after write operations to the FIFO is known to be complete:

```
wait until rising_edge(clk);
read_uplink_FIFO(clk);
```

I do not have much experience with procedures, and information concering my problem is limited. I am wondering if I am using the procedure wrong or if it is even possible to use a procedure for my objective.

I tried to switch around the nested if statement without any success:

```
if fifo_empty_o = '0' then
    if rising_edge(clk) then
    ...
    end if;
elsif fifo_empty_o = '1'  then
    .....
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would help if you posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . You do not show how the procedure is called. It could be called outside of a process (as an inferred processes) to be called every time `clk` changes, but your `rd_cnt` never get past 1 because the procedure would exit after a single clock. You probably want to learn about loops in VHDL which can be put inside your procedure.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response and the welcome. I edited my question followng the MVCE.

Comment: The only place you can define a procedure that assigns signals not declared as parameters is as a process declarative item. Noting the lack of a [mcve] your question's and Tricky's answer readers can neither validate the issue, the answer, or alternative solutions. If rdcnt were declared as an integer subtype with a range matching uplink_fifo_reg you could use a for loop with that range containing a wait for rising_edge(clk) that exits when fifo_empty_o = '1' adding clarity for a third party or future reader.

Answer (score 1):

This being a testbench, you can create a procedure that simply loops a number of times until the fifo is empty. A procedure along those lines would look something like this:

```vhdl
procedure read_uplink_FIFO(
    signal clk            : in std_logic;
    constant scope        : in string := C_SCOPE
    )is
    variable rd_cnt       : integer := 0; 
begin
  rd_ena_i                <= '1';

  while not fifo_empty_o loop     
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    
    
    uplink_fifo_reg(rd_cnt) <= rd_data_o;
    log(ID_SEQUENCER_SUB, "Data: (" & to_string(rd_data_o, HEX, AS_IS, INCL_RADIX) 
            & "), read from FIFO index: (" & to_string(rd_cnt) & ")", scope); 
    rd_cnt  := rd_cnt + 1;
  end loop;

  rd_ena_i    <= '0';
  log(ID_SEQUENCER_SUB, "Read complete, FIFO is empty", scope);

end procedure;
```

This is just an example. Please tailor to your own needs.

Comment: This looks much better, As I have learned that while loops are not supported for synthesis, it did not cross my mind to use it in the testbench.  Thank you for the clear answer and solution example.

Comment: while loops are supported in synthesis depending on how they're used

Comment: @yes, but this one won't be.